# Use purrr:map with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I don't have much experience using the `purrr` package. I have a dataframe named `data` which looks like this:

```
Country Year Incidence
USA     1995 20000
USA     2000 23000
UK      1995 16000
UK      2000 22000
```

It's confidential and I can't share it so this is just a small excrept. I need to make a plot where Year is on x-axis and incidence on y-axis, however, I need to have separate plots for each country. Faceting is unfortunately not an option, I need to save each plot as a separate file.

I know how I would split the dataframe, however, I don't know how to use `ggplot` inside of the `map` function. This is the code that I was trying with and is not working.

```
data %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  group_split() %>%
  map(ggplot, aes(x = Year, y = Incidence)+
        geom_line()+
        geom_point())
```

What would be the proper way to write this code?

Comment: If you just want to save these to the hard drive instead of adding them to a list, you can use the `walk()` function in purr and put your save command inside your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(tidyverse)

list_plot <- data %>%
               group_split(Country) %>%
               map(~ggplot(., aes(x = Year, y = Incidence) ) +
                       geom_line()+ geom_point())
```

You get list of plots in `list_plot` one for every `Country` which can be accessed using `list_plot[[1]]`, `list_plot[[2]]` etc.

Have you considered using facets for your plots?

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly! Do you know where I could find more information about the role of `~` because I don't quite understand what it does.

My initial idea was to use facets, however, I was told all plots need to be separate so that they can be included in the PowerPoint presentation with each slide showing one country.

Comment: I see, in that case this approach seems correct. `~` is formula-style syntax to apply a function. It is an alternative to an anonymous function. You can read about it in `?map`.