# ggplot - add title based on the variable in the dataframe used for plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60671310/use-purrrmap-with-ggplot?noredirect=1#comment107342430_60671310) where I asked how to use `ggplot` inside of `purr::map`.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

I have a dataframe named `data` which looks like this:

```
Country Year Incidence
USA     1995 20000
USA     2000 23000
UK      1995 16000
UK      2000 22000
```

I am using this code to make a year/incidence plot split by country (each country has a separate plot, not one single, but faceted plot for all countries).

```
list_plot <- data %>%
               group_split(Country) %>%
               map(~ggplot(., aes(x = Year, y = Incidence) ) +
                       geom_line()+ geom_point())
```

Now I would like to put the name of the country in the title of each of the graphs. I tried the following:

```
list_plot <- data %>%
               group_split(Country) %>%
               map(~ggplot(., aes(x = Year, y = Incidence) ) +
                       geom_line()+ geom_point() + labs(title = Country))
```

But it's not working (it's telling me the object 'Country' is not found). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.$Country` instead of `Country` should fix it

```
data = data.frame(Country = c('USA','USA','UK','UK'), 
                  Year = c(1995,2000,1995,2000), 
                  Incidence = c(20000,23000,16000,22000))

list_plot <- data %>%
  group_split(Country) %>%
  map(~ggplot(., aes(x = Year, y = Incidence) ) +
        geom_line()+ geom_point() + labs(title = .$Country))
```